# How is it possible that area under continuous curve consist of indivisibles?

Tags: synthetic-differential-geometry

I read in article (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuity/) that continuity can't consist of indivisibles, only discrete entity can:

> "In a word, continua are divisible without limit or infinitely
> divisible..."

> "In something like the same sense as a discrete entity
> is made up of its individual units, its “indivisibles”.."

But in John Bell's book (A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis) area under continuous curve consists of indivisibles:

[image]

How is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: A "continuum" and a "continuous function" are different concepts. Note also that the set of rationals is divisible, but not a continuum.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What is difference between "continuum" and "continuous function"?

Comment: The answer is really the same as to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4808837/72694